# drag and drop and resize div in jQuery

Tags: jquery, resize, drag

I have two spaces, the first have an artefacts serie (divs) and the second is a work area in which the artefacts dragged from the first space can be newly dragged and dropped, resized and join between these.
At the moment, I can (working about an example in the web) drag the artefacts and drop it in the work area, where I can drag and drop newly this artefact, but i can't resize it. To say true, I don't have tried to do the join between the artefacts but it would be of great help to me if please you say to me any idea to do it.
The code that I have  is:

```
jQuery(function(){

    counter = 0;

    jQuery('.Artefacto').draggable({
        helper: 'clone',
        containment: '#areaDibujo',
        stop:function(ev, ui) {
            //al arrastrar el primer elemento
            var pos=jQuery(ui.helper).offset();
            objName = "#clonediv"+counter
            jQuery(objName).css({
                "left":pos.left,
                "top":pos.top
            });
            jQuery(objName).removeClass("Artefacto");
            //Para elementos existentes en el área
            jQuery(objName).draggable({
                containment: 'parent',
                stop:function(ev, ui) {
                    var pos=jQuery(ui.helper).offset();
                }
            });
        }
    });

    jQuery("#areaDibujo").droppable({
        drop: function(ev, ui) {
            if (ui.helper.attr('id').search(/Artefacto[0-9]+/) != -1){
                counter++;
                var element=jQuery(ui.draggable).clone();
                element.addClass("tempclass");
                jQuery(this).append(element);
                jQuery(".tempclass").attr("id","clonediv"+counter);
                jQuery("#clonediv"+counter).removeClass("tempclass");
                //Get the dynamically item id
                draggedNumber = ui.helper.attr('id').search(/Artefacto([0-9]+)/)
                itemDragged = "dragged" + RegExp.$1
                jQuery("#clonediv"+counter).addClass(itemDragged);
            }
        }
    });

});
```

And the xhtml file is this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:icecore="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/core"
      xmlns:ace="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/components"
      xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"
      xml:lang="es" lang="es"
      >
    <h:head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <title>Drag and Drop</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./xmlhttp/css/rime/rime.css"/>-->
    </h:head>

    <h:body>

        <div id="contenedor">
            <div id="panelArtefactos">
                <h3>Artefactos</h3>
                <div id="Artefacto">
                    <div id="Artefacto1" class="Artefacto" styleClass="ui-widget-content">Entidad</div>
                    <br/>
                    <div id="Artefacto1" class="Artefacto">Claves</div>
                    <br/>
                    <div id="Artefacto1" class="Artefacto">Atributos</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="areaDibujo">
                AREA DE DIBUJO...
            </div>
        </div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

I will be very grateful if you can help me.

P.S.: Sorry if my english don't is correct :$ (shame of me)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the same example as you and I made it resizable!

```
var element=$(ui.draggable).clone();
element.addClass("tempclass");
$(element).resizable({
  helper: "ui-resizable-helper"
});                 
$(this).append(element);
```

I'm using helper just to show the borders of my new size.
The CSS is simple:

```
.ui-resizable-helper {
  border: 2px dotted #00F;
}
```